# VNC Black screen using GNOME

Tags: gnome, vnc, remote-desktop, xrdp

I was working in a Oracle Linux server through XRDP with Xvnc(TigerVNC) and the server crash.
After the crash I only can access the server through XRDP with Xorg, but not with Xvnc,
when I try to access using VNC I only have a black screen with the mouse pointer.

The file .xstartup was missing, the file vncserver@:1.service located in /etc/systemd/system was missing.

I try to reconfigure the vnc service

- Stop the service xrdp and vncserver
- Delete lock files loacated in /tmp
- Delete .Xauthority from home folder
- Create ~/.vnc/xstartup file

  unset SESSION_MANAGER
  unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
  /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
  vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
- Create /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service

  [Unit]
  Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
  After=syslog.target network.target

  [Service]
  Type=forking

  ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
  ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l vncuser -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"
  PIDFile=/home/vncuser/.vnc/%H%i.pid
  ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
- Start xrdp service
- execute systemctl daemon--reload
- Execute systemctl vncserver@:1.service
- Execute vncserver

The issue persist. I can connect using Xorg, but with Xvnc I only get a black screen with the mouse pointer

The server only have GNOME as GUI

Any Advice

Thanks In advance